Unable to change pointBackgroundColor after initial configuration is done using Chart.js
I am using Chart.js version 4.3.x. I am having issues creating different color points on a line graph. All the entries I see on StackOverflow are older versions. It's still listed in the API
I have added pointBackgroundColor into the initial config with a single entry in the array. Yet when I try to access it as in chart.data.dataset.pointBackgroundColor I'm getting an error that the property does not exist on the dataset.
datasets:
{
    label: 'Measured',
    data: [],
    pointStyle: ptStyle[1],
    borderColor: [],
    backgroundColor: '#0b7d22',
    pointBackgroundColor: ['#0b7d22']
},

chart.data.datasets.pointBackgroundColor // insert a different color

in the last line of code, I end up with the property doesn't exist error.
I've tried having both values in the array.
I've tried using ...datasets['pointBackgroundColor']
I was expecting to be able to set an individual point's color outside of the initial config, as I am loading the chart's data after the graph is created.

datasets is an array and not a single item. So you can't set a property on it. You need to target the correct index like so:
chart.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor = newColor

I am using datasets as an array, should have made that clear, "this.chart.data.datasets[1].pointBackgroundColor". The property still comes up as not available on the datasets selected in Eclipse. I can see the property when debugging the JS using browser tools. So, either Eclipse has an issue or the property vailidations for Chart.js has an issue.
